# Бекенд чата. Как создать 2 сущности - пользователи и сообщения?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

### Передо мной поставили следуюую задачу: Реализовать бекенд для чата. Создать 2 сущности - пользователи и сообщения.

Я не могу понять что от меня хотят в том смысле, что мне бы хоть раз увидеть, как эта задача выполняется последовательно. Теория - это одно, но как до практики - так абсолютно не ясна последовательность решения задачи. В такой формулировке я ничего понять не могу. Это как с высшей математикой - по одной лишь теории задачу не решишь, пока преподаватель не покажет. Так и тут:

- Каждая из сущностей реализовывает CRUD (create, read, update, delete)
  через REST (post, get, put, delete).
- Сущность пользователя содержит базовые поля (имя и пр.)
- Сущность сообщения содержит senderId и receiverId (id пользователей),
  а также тело сообщения.
- Создать роут, который возвращает всех пользователей, с которыми
  общался пользователь с данным id.
- Данные можно хранить в памяти (как в примере) или в MongoDB.
- Разбить ответственность модулей бекенда аналогично примеру - routes,
  services, опционально repositories.
- Описать все роуты в README.md репозитория

Запросы отсылать через Postman или другой аналогичный инструмент.
И дали пример: [Пример](https://github.com/RAYDENFilipp/bsa-2016-nodejs-lecture-showcase)

Comment: Где у вас конкретно возникли затруднения?

Comment: @0xdb, Я не монимаю, что конкретно стоит за словом "сущность", как эта "сущность" должна что-либо реализовывать. Я не понимаю, какой мой порядок действий. Например:
1. создайте файл А, Б, В...
2. прописать в,г,д..
3. и т.д.
Просто по заданию показали лекцию, в которой дали overview NodeJS и Express, но как выполнять задание пошагово, для примера, не объяснили. И у меня в голове получается разрыв: теорию в целом вроде понял, а как она получается на практике - нет. Особенно в контексте своей задачи и того примера, который мне дали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал использовать готовые модули для NodeJS: mongoose для mongo db + express; socket.io для онлайн обновления сообщений страницы чата; PassportJS для авторизации пользователей и сохранения их в бд, создания сессии, если он зашел под своим аккаунтом; express-socket.io-session как мидлвару для связи сессий пользователей и их текущих сокетов (так называются дуплексные соединения клиент-сервер, которые работают онлайн, обновляя сообщения на странице чата).

Я б начал бы с моделей для бд:

Сообщения:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dialog', {
    private: Boolean,
    senderId: String,
    receiver: [],
    message: String

});
```

и юзер:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    avatarPath: String
});
```

Потом бы присобачил passport с типом **локальной** авторизации, или, если нужно, через фейсбук, или вконтакте. Насадил бы express-socket.io-session в главном файле app.js сразу ж после инициализации экспресса вот так:

```
// Configuring Passport
    var passport = require('passport');
    var expressSession = require('express-session')({secret: 'g435kv823G-sv'});
    app.use(expressSession);
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    var sharedSession = require("express-socket.io-session");
    io.use(sharedSession(expressSession, {
        autoSave:true
    }));
```

Потом придумал бы что делать при отправке сообщения одного пользователя другому. Скорее всего, я бы принимал с помощью AJAX данные нового сообщения роутером, проверял бы авторизацию пользователя через пасспорт, если ок - записывал бы в бд в таблицу сообщений новое сообщение и перебирал через цикл все активные сокеты, искал бы в них receiverId, чтобы отправить ему сообщение:

```
for (var i in io.sockets.connected) {
    if (io.sockets.connected[i].handshake.session.hasOwnProperty('passport')) {
         if (dialog.receiver.includes(io.sockets.connected[i].handshake.session.passport.user)) {                                                      
              io.sockets.connected[io.sockets.connected[i].id].emit('new message', newMessage);
              }
         }
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Можешь объяснить, для чего эта строчка?
 `var expressSession = require('express-session')({secret: 'g435kv823G-sv'});`

Comment: Да, забыл пояснить. В бд должны хранится сессии пользователей. Этот модуль создает таблицу с временными записями сессий пользователей, там хранится кука для сопоставления с кукой из браузера пользователя для авторизации. Модуль express-socket.io-session позволяет связать таблицу сессий с сокетами этого пользователя.

Comment: 'g435kv823G-sv' - это и есть та самая "кука"?

Comment: нет. Куки формируются автоматически, пасспорт их отправляет в браузер в куки сессий при успешной авторизации.  А это для защиты куки.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать `ODM` если это `mongodb` (я бы посоветовал `mongoose`, лёгкая в использовании), если это (`mysql`, `postgress`, итд...), то `sequelize`. "Cоздать 2 сущности" - это грубо говоря создать 2 (таблицы/коллекции) в базе данных, связать их между собой ключами, у вас описано что таблица `messages` должна иметь ключи отправителя и получателя. Если вы работали хоть с одной базой данных, то должны понимать о чем идёт речь.

Так же в вашем приложении на `express` нужно создать пути для обработки, обновлений данных, то есть путь по которому мы обратитесь через `ajax` с определенными параметрами, код обработает что-то там, мб запишет в бд и отдаст ответ.

На примере: делаете запрос на адрес `/message/add` с такими данными, как `senderId, receiverId, text и что-то еще, если нужно`, далее ваш код проверяет имеет ли право писать 1 чел. второму (если нужно), проверяет на запрещенные символы, мб что-то еще делает, заносит данные в бд и по соккетам отправляем данные о новом сообщении получателю, а отправителю через `res.json`, что сообщение было отправлено. Вот примерно так, в кратце это всё делается.