# Как от общего чата на node.js перейти к пересональной переписке

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Пишу небольшой чат на node.js. Сейчас чат общий. При отправке сообщения в чат оно появляется у всех пользователей. Как реализовать возможность отправки сообщений конкретному пользователю?

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('3000 is run');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('new client here');

    socket.on('message', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<button id="send">Send</button>
</body>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');

    document.querySelector('#send')
        .addEventListener('click', ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();

            let text = document.querySelector('#message').value;

            socket.emit('message', text);
        })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: у каждого пользователя есть свой `socketId`, соответственно emit нужно посылать на него а не на все - `io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit(...);`. Скорее всего его можно выцепить в socket тут - `io.on('connection', function(socket)`

Comment: Возможно, в будущем вам понадобится бд с пользователями для авторизации и историей сообщений. Если да, можете глянуть сюда:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693164/190886